# How to switch HP printer from CDROM mode to Printer/Scanner mode

Tags: usb, printing, sane

I have an HP multifunction printer/scanner M1123 MFP. I installed the latest hplip that should support it and also hp-plugin. However, when I plug the device in, I only see a CDROM detected in `dmesg`. `lsusb` only shows "Hewlett Packard"  without anything else.

This is one of those devices that shows up as a CDROM and then auto-installs the driver on Windows.

Is there some command to make it switch from CDROM/USB memory more to "Printer/scanner" mode? `xsane` reports that it fails to find any device.

Comment: Please add information about the OS you are using.

Comment: Apparently it is not supported on old Slackware 12.1 kernel. I installed Slackware 13.37 and everything works out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your system has proper kernel modules loaded, it should be enough to run `eject /dev/sr0` (*assuming `/dev/sr0` is the printer's virtual cdrom device - see `dmesg` to check this*). You will probably need root privileges for that (run with `sudo`).

Comment: Since kernel was the problem, this answer is closest to the real thing, so I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [HPLIP faq](http://hplipopensource.com/node/294) say there is a menu option for other printers (the HP A530 / A630).  Did you see an option in the printer menu for disabling "Software Install Mode"?